# jQuery validate submitHandler não funciona no firefox

Tags: jquery, ajax

Com a seguinte função abaixo, consigo enviar os dados via ajax tranquilamente no Chrome, mas ao testar no Firefox, não ocorre erro e os dados não são enviados.

```
$('#form_lista_amiga').validate({
    rules : {
        cpf: { required: true, cpf: true }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {

        var data = $( form ).serialize();
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo Router::url(array('controller' => 'ListaAmiga', 'action' =>'add'), true); ?>",
            type: 'POST',
            datatype: 'json',
            data: data,
            success: function(data){
                $('#lista_amiga_msg').html(data);
                // alert(data);
            }
        });  
        return false;   
    }
});
```

Comment: Qual erro acontece quando você tenta enviar no Firefox? Poderia nos dizer por favor?

Comment: Podes criar um exmplo no jsFiddle que tenha o problema que referes? (ou talvez o @PauloHDSousa?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dei uma fuçada aqui com o seu código e cheguei à conclusão de que o `event.preventDefault()` causa uma discrepância do funcionamento entre o FireFox e o Chrome.

Se o código contiver um `event.preventDefault()` então funciona no Chrome, mas no FireFox não funciona... ao invés disso ele parece submeter o formulário normalmente.

Ao comentar a linha do `event.preventDefault()`, ai o FireFox passou a se comportar da mesma forma que o Chrome.

Esse foi o código que eu testei e funcionou em ambos os browsers:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/libs/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/libs/jquery.validate-1.13.1.js"></script>
    <link href="/libs/bootstrap-3.2.0.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {

            jQuery.validator.addMethod("cpf", function(value, element) {
                return (/\d{3}.\d{3}.\d{3}-\d{2}/g).test(value);
            }, "* CPF inválido");

            $('#form_lista_amiga').validate({
                rules : {
                    cpf: { required: true, cpf: true }
                },
                submitHandler: function(form) {

                    var data = $( form ).serialize();
                    //event.preventDefault();
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "add",
                        type: 'POST',
                        datatype: 'json',
                        data: data,
                        success: function(data){
                            alert(data);
                        }
                    });  
                    return false;

                }
            });

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form_lista_amiga">
        <input id="cpf" name="cpf" />
        <input type="submit" value="send" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Marcelo de Andrade funcionou ?

Comment: Exatamente, Miguel. Verifiquei que o event.preventDefault() não funciona corretamente no Firefox pois não foi iniciliazado a variável event. Aqui a dica: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585970/jquery-event-preventdefault-not-working-in-firefox-jsfiddle-included

Comment: Pra falar a verdade, descobri o problema fazendo busca binária (quase binária)... nem havia me atentado para o fato de o `event` não estar inicializado.

Comment: Dei uma pesquisada sobre isso, parece que `event` definido na `window` é invenção da Microsoft e seu bendito IE. O Chrome, provavelmente para ter maior compatibilidade, define esta variável na `window`, mas o FireFox não.

Answer (score 0):

se pretende usar o evento,use esse padrão:

```
$("#form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}).validate({
    rules: {...},
    submitHandler: function(form) { 
        //codigo
        return false;
    }
});
```